# SOA 11g ftp pipeline valve issue

Tags: oracle11g, ftp, soa, pipeline

I created valve in my FTP adapter to decrypt a file. I am using SOA 11g. But for some unknown reason, the pipeline gets completely skipped and the adapter reads encrypted data from the file. Due to this it fails a schema validation. Below is my jca code:

```
<property name="PipelineFile" value="Pipeline.xml"/>
```

And my pipeline:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
<pipeline xmlns="http://www.oracle.com/adapter/pipeline">
    <valves>
            <valve>DecryptPGPValve</valve>
    </valves>
</pipeline>
```

Appreciate any help.